# Problema com Json para carregar dados na api do gmaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

Estou usando *Rails* em um projeto da faculdade e adicionei a *API do Gmaps* ao meu projeto, nela eu pretendo exibir vários pontos no mapa pegando as coordenadas de um arquivo *JSON* para criar o *cluster*.

Porém a função que fiz não funciona de forma alguma, o mapa aparece porém sem nenhum ponto colocado nele, estou utilizando também a biblioteca *jQuery*. Meu arquivo *JSON* se encontra dentro da minha pasta `Javascripts` no *Rails*, segue abaixo meu código:

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
        //Opções de iniciação do mapa

        function initMap() {
            var cin = {lat: -8.055590, lng: -34.951344}
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: cin
        });


        //Função de carregar pontos do Json e jogar no mapa

        function carregarPontos() {
          $.getJSON('javascripts/pontos.json', function(pontos) {
             for (var i = 0; i < pontos.points.length; i++){
             var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pontos.points[i][0], pontos.points[i][1]);
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latLng,
             map: map
               });
            }

          });
        }

        //Infoboxes 

        var contentString = '<h1 id="pintest">Teste</h1>';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                 infowindow.open(map, marker);
         });

        }
        //Iniciando função de carregar pontos

        carregarPontos();
```

Meu arquivo *Pontos.json* tá nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu não tenho certeza se está no formato certo, mas fiz o teste com outro arquivo *JSON* que está nesse formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E também não roda, meu mapa aparece porém sem nenhum ponto nele.